# How to change fill color for svg image inside object element?

Tags: html, svg

Now I have this code:

```
object(type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/services/web-development-icon.svg")
```

Guys, how can I change the color of image?
CSS code below not working:

```
object {fill: red}
```

Comment: edit the SVG file change the fill color is simplest.

Comment: yeah, I found `<g id="filler" fill="#FFFFFF">` element inside, and I can change inline style color, but why I can't do this in CSS?

Comment: Because it's a different document and CSS is per-document. You can do it in CSS if you put the CSS in the svg file itself.